# Not able to display contents of List/ data not added to list

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a program to partition the database based on the modvalue. To do this I am using a list of lists (`listoflists`), which will contain one list for one partition. But when I run this, the contents of the lists are not displayed, or maybe the data is not getting added into the list.
Here is the code:

```
//List of lists
List<List<Integer>> listoflists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

while(rs.next()) {
    int rollno = rs.getInt(1);
    data = Integer.toString(rollno);
    //calculating hmac value
    int hmacvalue = dbpartition.hmacSha1(data, ks);
    modvalue = Math.abs(hmacvalue % wl);
    System.out.println("modvalue is " + modvalue);

    for(int i = 1; i <= wl; i++)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //System.out.println("List created");
        if(i == modvalue)
        {
            list.add(rollno);
            System.out.println("data added to List");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(listoflists);
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
The hash of the tuple is 37529665
modvalue is 4
data added to List

The hash of the tuple is -1387128724
modvalue is 7
data added to List

The hash of the tuple is 636638561
modvalue is 0

The hash of the tuple is 435523502
modvalue is 11
data added to List

[]
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be adding `list` to (I assume) `Listoflists`...

Answer (score 1):

You never add `list` to `ListOflists`.

BTW: Pick one naming convention and stick to it. I'd suggest `ListOflists` should be called `listOfLists`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your lists to your `Listoflists` anywhere, so it remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. I added data to the list.I have modified my code this way

```
 List<List<Integer>> Listoflists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();//List of lists
            List<Integer> list = null;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int rollno=rs.getInt(1);
                data=Integer.toString(rollno);
                int hmacvalue=dbpartition.hmacSha1(data, ks);
                modvalue = Math.abs(hmacvalue % wl);
                System.out.println("modvalue is"+modvalue);

                for(int i=1;i<=wl;i++)
                {
                    int rownum=rs.getRow();
                    if(rownum==1) //for first row create partitions or lists
                    {
                    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    System.out.println("List created");
                    Listoflists.add(list);
                    //System.out.println(Listoflists);
                    }
                    if(i==modvalue)
                    {
                        //list.add(rownum);
                        Listoflists.get(i-1).add(rownum);
                        System.out.println("row number added to List");
                    }

                }
               // Listoflists.add(list);

            }
           System.out.println(Listoflists);
```

I have got the output as:

[[39], [8, 28, 29, 41], [5, 23], [1, 6, 9, 12, 13, 17, 24, 33, 50], [31, 38], [42], [2, 15, 47, 49, 51], [10, 11, 18, 20, 21, 22, 26, 35, 45], [19], [7, 14, 16, 25, 27, 32, 46], [4, 36, 37, 43], [34, 40, 44, 48], []]

I have got list of lists correctly.